# Could the Deutsche Kaiserreich create a U-Boat with the following capabitities for the WWI if some timetraveler give them the blueprints?

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds

Is possible to design a submarine that follows the following restrictions?

1. It must have at least the capabilities of a early „the war to end all wars“ U-Boat (e.g. [SM U-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM_U-19_(Germany))).
2. It must build-able with 1910 technology or earlier.
3. It must be able to move underwater in a competitive speed like the Type XXI.
4. It must be able to shot underwater like the Type XXI.
5. It must be able to be underwater for hours like the Type XXI.
6. It cannot cost more than 2.5 submarines of the Kriegsmarine in that epoch.
7. Their capabilities must remain secret.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: you are asking if something with the capabilities of a submarine ordered in 1910 and built in 1911 can be made with the technology of 1910?

Comment: @L.Dutch, the way I read it the OP wants 1910 capabilities *plus* extra submerged endurance and performance.

Comment: @L.Dutch I am asking if something with more than the capabilities of a submarine of 1911 and built in 1910 can be made with the technology of 1910.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the price requirement is for series production, not the first prototype.

- The first key technology is the [snorkel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_snorkel), but the reason for the snorkel were aircraft with radar, so why try? Still, it seems plausible that a snorkel should be built at marginal extra cost.
- The second key technology is the large battery capacity. Sounds again as if there should be no problem to create the batteries, but it could be a problem to squeeze them into a 1910s-style hull with all the other 1910s-style fittings. [CO2 scrubbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber#Minerals_and_zeolites) are also possible.
- Sensors might be a problem, even with blueprints. That goes both for the sonar and the radar. Underwater firing solutions from a periscope?
- Crush depth would depend on the quality of steel, not easily handled by imported blueprints.

My gut feeling is that for a relatively modest price increase, there could be significant increases in submerged performance plus a snorkel. But to get anywhere near the submerged performance of a Type XXI in any one specific area with 1910s technology crowds an already crowded design. Extra batteries would come at the expense of fuel, diesel engines, or armament. Extra electric motors would come at the expense of diesels, batteries, or armament. (... wait, didn't we just cut diesels to make room for more batteries!?)

Comment: You are making several mistakes, the first is to assume I want radar and/or SONAR or any other modern sensor in the U-Boat. But my question was about enhanced capabilities of travel. Second that it will have a 1910-style hull, because to accomplish with requirement #3 you need a hull more appropriate to underwater travel. Neither I am asking to a higher deep. Where still haven't figured SONAR or aviation.

Comment: @LucieWillers, you wanted submered firing, right? That requires a sensor for submerged detection and targeting, and a periscope is very limited in this regard.

Comment: the periscope should be good enough for a 1910 submarine.

Comment: @LucieWillers, perhaps for the attack run, but how will it find shipping if it cruises submerged with questionable sonars?

Comment: Like they did in „The War to End All Wars“. They did have to spot first the target, and they set course towards the target, Just this time can approach and retreat without being spotted until SONAR is introduced, but then surely will be new countermeasures.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to construct that submarine, although I'm doubtful that it can be done for the price. The bigger question is if it's actually *useful*?

The WWII-era Type XXI was built to be able to attack heavily defended convoys. The escorts of those convoys had effective radar, sonar, and fast-sinking anti-submarine weapons, which had made early-WWII U-boats obsolete.

During the [historical WWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_U-boat_campaign_of_World_War_I), convoys were not introduced until May 1917. The strategy used by the U-boats changed several times during the war, and unrestricted sinking of merchant ships, regardless of political consequences, was not adopted until early 1917, after which convoys were introduced quite quickly. Assuming it was a slightly-lower-tech version of the WWII Battle of the Atlantic is mistaken: both sides in WWII had done a lot of thinking about any new submarine campaign, and started with different strategies from the previous war.

So the buildability of a submarine that matches some of the capabilities of a Type XXI is a bit of a *non-sequitur* unless you know how it's going to be used. It's unlikely to be worth the cost in the absence of WWII-era radar and sonar.

You need to start by planning a different strategy from the historical one, and then design U-boats that suit it.

Answer (score 1):

No. While blueprints themselves can represent a tremendous amount of work that the people in 1910 would not have to perform themselves, rarely is it the case that the trouble for people in earlier times is that they don't know what *design* to use to maximize the effectiveness of a machine (or to make it at all).

Submarines in particular rely on very sophisticated materials that may not be possible to manufacture in 1910 (especially when the blueprints do not cover how to make those). They sometimes rely on materials that may not even be available (during the Cold War, US submarines needed titanium, which for the most part was only available from mines in the USSR). The designs for the manufacturing processes can be quite complicated, and may rely on some significant institutional knowledge... that is, even with the machines that can make these new materials, and the raw ores themselves, the workers still need to know how to use those machines in subtle, nuanced ways, and that this knowledge is never written down (hell, sometimes writing it down won't help someone else to be able to do it).

Even for WWII-era submarines, there will be a few components which fall into categories like those I've outlined above. While some improvements could be made to the submarines of the WWI era simply by passing knowledge to them, these improvements are likely to be modest and incapable of changing the larger outcome.